# Javascript ES2017: Nested async await in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm attempting to call nested async functions inside a class, if that's even possible with the new async / await feature in 2017.

Heres some example code, which I'm running with NodeJS v7.7.2:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
class Counter {
    async run() {
        await this.one();
        await this.two();
        await this.three();
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        });
    }
    async one() {
        console.log('one');
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        });
    }
    async two() {
        console.log('two');
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        });
    }
    async three() {
        console.log('three');
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        });
    }
}
exports.Counter = Counter;
let counter = new Counter();
counter.run();
```

What I'm expecting to happen is this code to print
one
two 
three

However, it only prints
one

It seems that the subsequent calls to this.two() and this.three are not being made. Been trying to debug this problem for a couple of days.

Comment: What are all these `new Promise`s doing there that you never resolve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your promises never resolve:

```
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    });
```

There should be some call to `resolve` in there. But if you were just trying to make the `async` function return a promise, then don't create a promise at all: `async` functions always return a promise, and this already happens when the first `await` is encountered. The promised *value* is whatever you return with `return`. So don't return a promise, but nothing (i.e. `undefined`) or some other value that you would like the promise to resolve to.

Just to illustrate, in browsers that support `async` (e.g. Firefox 52+), the following snippet will output *one, two, three*:

```js
class Counter {
    async run() {
        await this.one();
        await this.two();
        await this.three();
    }
    async one() {
        console.log('one');
    }
    async two() {
        console.log('two');
    }
    async three() {
        console.log('three');
    }
}
let counter = new Counter();
counter.run();
```

Comment: You don't even need `Promise.resolve`, just `return` nothing. Or don't `return` anything at all if there's no result value.

Comment: Explicitly returning a promise from a function/method marked `async` is superfluous, as any return value will automatically be wrapped by a promise (that's what `async` does).